# iterating multidimensional array with enhanced for loop java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, foreach

When iterating through array x with an enhanced for loop what do y and z represent and how does the loop work. Here is the code I have written, it works but I don't understand exactly why and how it works. If someone could explain the syntax of the for loop when displaying a multidimensional array I would appreciate it.

```
// enhanced for loop
String[][] x =
{
    {"a", "a^2", "a^3"},
    {"1", "1", "1"},
    {"2", "4", "8"},
    {"3", "9", "27"},
    {"4", "16", "64"}    
};

for (String[] y: x)
{
    for (String z: y)
    {
        System.out.print(z + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Do you have an instructor to whom you can redirect these tutorial type questions?

Comment: I would start out with the basic for loop. If you can understand this tutorial: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html then move on to the enhanced for loop: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with, which after understanding how the enhanced for loop works, you should have no problem linking the concept of multidimensional arrays with enhanced for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Java for each loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 1):

An enhanced for loop over an array is equivalent to iterating over the indices of the array in a regular for loop :

```
for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
    String[] y = x[i];
    for (int j=0; j<y.length; j++)
    {
        String z = y[j];
        System.out.print(z + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

When you are iterating over a two dimentional array, each element of the outer array, is itself an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String[] y: x)
```

Means 'for each String array (Called y) in the array of arrays (Called x)'.

So y[0], for example is   `{"a", "a^2", "a^3"}`

Then similarly, `for (String z: y)`
means 'for each String called z in the String array we previously defined as y.

So z[0] at the first pass of y is "a".  Then z[1] is "a^2" and z[2] is "a^3".

This completes the iteration of the first entry of y, and we repeat with the next one, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

what s happening is your by your first `for (String[] y: x)`your going through each element in the x, those happen to be of type String[], arrays of strings, and for each one of theme you iterate over its element by the second loop `for (String z: y)`, and thus y would be :
("a", "a^2", "a^3"),
("1", "1", "1"),
("2", "4", "8"),
.
.
and values for z would be a, a^2, a^3, 1 ....

Answer (score 0):

You could conceptually think of a 2D array to be an array of arrays.  Each element of level 1 array stores reference to another array and each element of level 2 array is the actual data, in this case, an  'int'.